# Can I simply delete the mongod.lock file and restart the mongod process?

Tags: mongodb

I use MongoDB 3.0 with WiredTiger engine.
I have a replication set with one primary and one arbiter.
The mongod process of my primary was killed with the signal '9'.
When I restart the mongod process, it gave the log message as below:
`Detected unclean shutdown - /data2/mongodb3.0/shard02_2/data/mongod.lock is not empty.`
Can I delete the mongod.lock file and restart the mongod process?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In the end I just removed it from the folder and re-ran mongod and everything worked fine. It just created a new mongod.lock file.
However, I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it.